# Undefined method 'action' running single RSpec file for a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec, webrat

I have a peculiar situation - an rspec file fails when run independently, but run okay when run as part of the entire suite.

```
Failure/Error: visit oauth_callback_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `action' for MyController:Class
     # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
     # ./spec/requests/login_spec.rb:xx:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/login_spec.rb:xx:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Simplified spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class MyController
  def oauth_response
    sign_in(
        ENV['TEST_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
        ENV['TEST_ACCESS_SECRET'])
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end


describe 'logging in' do
  it 'login' do
    visit oauth_callback_path
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your route for `oauth_callback_path` look like?

Comment: basic `match 'oauth_callback' => 'my#oauth_response'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class MyController` appears to be blocking Rails magic class loading.  Either the test should explicitly `require` the controller, or the extension should be defined with `MyController.class_eval`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that `MyController` is not extending `ApplicationController`. That's why the method `action` is not defined for `MyController`.